# 403 error after adding .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm not sure why but when adding a .htaccess file in a sub directory on my server everything in the folder gets a 403.

Code being used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule hash/ poll.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule empty/ blank.php
```

I can't for the life of my figure this out. I don't think I have ever added a htaccess file to a sub directory so perhaps their are different rules?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/

RewriteRule ^hash/ poll.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^empty/ blank.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Still getting a forbidden message :/

Comment: What is your URL generating 403? Do you have any .htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT dir?

Comment: Yes and Yes to answer your questions.

Comment: I asked what URL did you try to test?